# How to smooth a simple shape in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to make my own custom triangle shape and note that I'm extremely new to photoshop. I've watched at least 10 videos about my issue before posting this, I searched everywhere on google but there was no answer and maybe because the answer is too simple, but I've looked everywhere in photoshop. I made a triangle:
[image]

What I want to do is make it something like this:

[image]

Photoshop is extremely noob unfriendly, there's this rasterizing layers, smart objects, whatever that is and I'm just unable to smooth it out.

What I've tried:
I tried selecting the pixels and then using the Feather method. That only readjusts my selection, not the image. I then tried blurring it, but it doesn't work, nothing happens. 
I'm left with but one option and that is to manually erase and do my edges, but that will make everything really uneven, I might as well use Paint for that

I've become really desperate and I'm sorry if this is one of the worst questions asked here, I just need an answer

Comment: Even though you got some answers that got you where you wanted to be, I'd like to warn you that Photoshop simply is not the right software to do things like these with. The operation you describe is beyond trivial in a vector graphics editor like Illustrator or Inkscape, and devilishly difficult in a raster editor like Photoshop. If you have acces to a vector editor, create your shape there and paste/import it into Photoshop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the selection active:

- **Paths Panel Menu** > **Make Work Path** > Tolerance = 2,0
- **Brush Tool** > select a round brush, big diameter and set the spacing to 1%
- **Paths Panel** > Click the Path > Click the **Stroke Path Icon**

[image: Stroke Path]

- Fill the inside part of the triangle

[image: triangle]

Comment: Yup, worked like a charm. Thank you. Wish there was an easier way, but It works

Answer (score 2):

There is a low level approach to smoothing a black and white image that will work in any image editing software, including Photoshop.

#### 1. Start with a black and white image without transparency

[image: Black and white image]

#### 2. Apply gaussian blur

[image: blurred image]

#### 3. Open Levels and move the black and white point sliders towards the midtone slider

This increases the contrast of the image which will sharpen the edges. Pushing the three sliders to a single point will create a monochrome image, but often you want to leave some distance between them to get some nice anti-aliasing.

[image: compressed levels]

#### Done

[image]

To convert this to a transparent image you can go to Channels, create a selection out of one of the channels and then fill the selection with some color.

Comment: That worked great! You can even adjust the sliders to dynamically smooth

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way:

- Draw a triangle using the Polygon Tool (<kbd>U</kbd>), that's what vector shapes are for
- Now looking at the Tool options in the top bar, add a Stroke with the same color as the fill (highlighted on the left)
  [image]
- make sure that "Align Edges" is checked (highlighted on the right)
- Open the Stroke options (highlighted in the center) and make sure that the Stroke is:

  1. aligned to the Outside
  2. has round caps
  3. has round corners

[image]

That's it! If you need to resize your object, it will always be smooth.